# Human-readable strings for [NSImage imageTypes] identifiers?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, uti

Put simply, how does one retrieve a human-readable string (for instance, "Portable Network Graphics") for the type of identifier found in the array returned by [NSImage imageTypes] (for instance, "public.png" or "com.microsoft.bitmap")? I've read through the various pieces of documentation for universal type identifiers, but couldn't find anything. Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `UTTypeCopyDescription()` does what you're looking for:

```
NSArray *types = [NSImage imageTypes];
for (NSString *type in types) {
    NSString *desc = (NSString *)UTTypeCopyDescription((CFStringRef)type);
    NSLog(@"description for %@: %@", type, desc);
    [desc release];
}
```

Output:

> description for com.adobe.pdf: Portable Document Format (PDF)
>   description for com.apple.pict: QuickDraw picture
>   description for com.adobe.encapsulated-postscript: Encapsulated PostScript
>   description for public.jpeg: JPEG image
>   description for public.png: Portable Network Graphics image
>   description for com.compuserve.gif: Graphics Interchange Format (GIF)
>   description for public.jpeg-2000: JPEG 2000 image
>   description for com.canon.tif-raw-image: Canon TIF raw image
>   description for com.adobe.raw-image: Adobe raw image
>   etc....